# d3 rects inside rect, accessing and drawing nested elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to create a rect that contains several rects. So the output would look like this for one row (without attributes besides class):

```
<g class="rects">
  <rect class="rect"></rect>
  <g class="rectChildren">
    <rect class="rectChild1"></rect>
    <rect class="rectChild2"></rect>
    <rect class="rectChild3"></rect>
  </g>
</g>
```

However, I do not know how to access and draw this with a nested foreach loop in d3 (see code comment).

**Json:**

```
[
  {"name":"A", "rect":{"x":0, "width":600}, "rectChildren":[{"x":0, "width":200}, {"x":200, "width":200}, {"x":400, "width":200}]},
  {"name":"B", "rect":{"x":0, "width":1200}, "rectChildren":[{"x":0, "width":400}, {"x":400, "width":400}, {"x":800, "width":400}]}
]
```

**Code:**

```
var data;
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
    if (error) throw error;
    data = flare;
});
var nodes = tree.nodes(data);
var barHeight = 40;

// Update the nodes…
var rects = svg.selectAll("g.rects")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

//first group
var rectsEnter = rects.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "rects");

rectsEnter
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * (10 + barHeight); })
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
    .style("fill", "blue");

var rectChildren = rectsEnter
    //here I need something like:
    //foreach(r in d.rectChildren)
    //do
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rectChild")
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * barHeight + 10; })
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
    .style("fill", "green");
```

Comment: First, you should adjust your code, since you have no control over the  data array since the d3.json function is AJAX call hence asynchronous. The easiest fix is to move the closing brackets of the function to the end. To loop through the children you can write var rectChildren = rectEnter.selectAll('rect.rectChild').data(function(d) {return d.rectChildren;}).enter().append('rect')...

Comment: Sorry my data function is missing the first argument. Can you post your complete code?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed to know. Did not know I could call data(function(d) {return d.rectChildren;} Btw for everyone who is also struggling with nesting elements in d3: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Comment: Well, you one more argument (the data itself, the key function is the second argument). See http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.de/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175624/d3-key-function