# D3.js data key function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some troubles to understand the key function of the data method. I know how the 'data join' is working. That question doesn't ask an explication of how the 'enter' section is created.

Here you find a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/milottit/gv1qvdL2/10/. I use the key function but the output is not what I expected. Why when I use this key function `function(d, i) { return i; }` the first two data values are bound to the existing paragraph? I noticed that if I use whatever key function that uses `i` like `function(d, i) { return "azerty"+i; }` the results is always the same. The two first data values are bound. See http://jsfiddle.net/milottit/gv1qvdL2/11/.

What I was expecting is that I should use this following key function instead `function(d, i) { return "Already existing paragraph " + i; }` to bind the first two values.

What is happening?

Comment: The `key` function returns something to uniquely identify the node.  By default, it just uses the index of the node.  Appending a constant string to the index makes no difference in the "uniqueness" of that identifier, the already existing `p`s still have an index in the selection.  Contrast that with a [key function](http://jsfiddle.net/gv1qvdL2/14/) like `return d;` since your first two `p`s have no data, all data points `enter()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Key Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175624/d3-key-function)