# What is the deference between .data(data) vs .data(data, function(d) {return d;})?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was following the d3 tutorial:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221

I could not figure out the difference between data join `.data(data)` and `.data(data, function(d) {return d;})` in the second link http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221 When I change the `.data(data, function(d) {return d;})` to `.data(data)` the result is quite weird. Seems that the first couple of letters will not change. Can someone help me out?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175624/d3-key-function).  Also the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#data) explains it quite well.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Mark. I do not have much coding experience and did not know that is called a key function. I guess that is why I missed the posted question.